# Any ideas on how to make this using pure css? Text clipping to background image

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've tried using background-clip: text 
The problem I'm encountering is having the background white with the image showing through the text, I've tried using z index thinking that would work. I'm not sure if this is even possible, just looking for creative ideas.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmpbyP

```
background: url('http://unsplash.it/720x766');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
 -webkit-background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
```

this is what i came up with, tell me what you think/ if the code could be better in any way. the codepen link isn't working when i click it, its like stuck in a refresh loop??

Comment: Try to provide at least some code that you've tried. It's hard to help you when we have to guess what you did wrong. Also, this article provides a few examples: https://css-tricks.com/css-techniques-and-effects-for-knockout-text/

Comment: You can use the unofficial `-webkit-background-clip: text` (only with prefix) supported in Firefox, Chrome and Safari